# Pass "i" from a for loop into an onclicklistener event in the for loop

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to pass in "i" from this for loop into the onclicklisteners that I'm creating in the for loop, but I get an error because i isn't "final" I've tried storing i in a different final variable but that didn't work out and I can't just initialize i as final because it needs to change obviously.

How do I do this?  I want to be able to getText from button[i] from the button array passed into the method

```
public void applyClick(final Button button[], final TextView texty[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            switch(i) {
                case 0:case 1:case 2:case 3: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int c = getChange(button[0].getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + button[i].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            int m = Integer.parseInt(texty[0].getText().toString())+c;
                            texty[0].setText("" + m);
                            if (m <= 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 1 Loses!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
                case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int c = getChange(button[i].getText().toString());
                            int m = Integer.parseInt(texty[1].getText().toString())+c;
                            texty[1].setText("" + m);
                            if (m <= 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 2 Loses!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                    });
                }
                break;
                case 8:case 9:case 10:case 11: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int c = getChange(button[i].getText().toString());
                            int m = Integer.parseInt(texty[2].getText().toString())+c;
                            texty[2].setText("" + m);
                            if (m <= 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 3 Loses!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
                case 12:case 13:case 14:case 15: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int c = getChange(button[i].getText().toString());
                            int m = Integer.parseInt(texty[3].getText().toString())+c;
                            texty[3].setText("" + m);
                            if (m <= 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 4 Loses!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the OnClickListener and create a constructor with
an int parameter.

```
public class ParameterizedOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

  int mIntValue;
  public ParameterizedOnClickListener(int mIntValue) 
  {
    this.mIntValue= mIntValue;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    //use your mIntValue
  }
}
```

...

```
button[i].setOnClickListener( new ParameterizedOnClickListener(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `final` in the declaration

```
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
  final int i=j;
        switch(i) {
```

Note : In android Studio (if you're using it) just press `Alt`+`Enter` to fix similar errors , this will add the 'final' automatically ..it will helps you in other cases such as adding `try`+`catch` and a lot of things , 
just remember : When you get Error like this TRY ALT+ENTER